# Rails e MySQL - Tipos de Dados

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Comecei a utilizar Ruby on Rails recentemente para um projeto, e tenho dúvidas quanto ao scaffold e outras funcionalidades de DB presentes no Rails.

Aqui há um tópico explicando sobre tipos de dados no Active Record Migration
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918117/rails-4-list-of-available-datatypes

Como posso utilizar outros tipos de dados presentes no MySQL, como Set, Enum e tantos outros? Posso alterar tabelas diretamente pelo MySQL ou tenho que seguir exatamente o que as migrações do Active Record oferecem?

Answer (score 1):

O **Rails** utiliza `ActiveRecord` (*ORM*) para fazer o mapeamento de todas as tabelas e atributos das mesmas. Então para você utilizar o **Rails** sem utilização de bibliotecas externas, **sim** você só poderá utilizar os dados oferecidos pelas migrações do **Rails**.

No entanto você pode extender essas funcionalidades utilizando uma [Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems). Para seu caso, se precisa utilizar `SET` ou `ENUM` do `MySQL` pode utilizar a gem [native_enum](https://github.com/iangreenleaf/native_enum) que, segundo a documentação, adiciona esses dois tipos à migração do **Rails**. Ex:

```
create_table :balloons, :force => true do |t|
  t.enum "color", :limit => ['red', 'gold'], :default => 'gold', :null => false
  # or...
  t.column "size", :enum, :limit => ['small', 'medium', 'large']
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A ideia do migration é ter registrado como scripts a evolução do seu banco de dados, dessa forma voce teria a a gestão de mudança de banco de dados documentada, alem de facilitar a atualização do banco junto com código da aplicação, facilidade na aplicação de muitos scripts e equalização de banco entre ambientes, por exemplo. Com migrations voce poderá evoluir ou regredir o banco baseado na evolução histórica junto com seu código. Aconselho a não mexer diretamente no banco de dados a não ser que sejam tarefas especificas de tunning ou gestão, ou que voce não consiga fazer com migrations (Raríssimas exceções).

No rails 4 voce pode fazer Enum da seguinte maneira [DOC](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Ou voce pode executar queries no migration, [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856856/how-to-write-sql-in-a-migration-in-rails).